# Produce blocks only if there are incoming transactions

Tags: consensus

Is there a way to produce blocks only if there are incoming transactions. Thus not producing empty blocks?
Do we need to build a palette for that or what exactly?

Comment: Check out Substate Contract Node. It only produces blocks on incoming txs.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61559807

Comment: thanks @bruno this link is helpfull